# Fontconfig: specify which bold font to use

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I have an embedded application where I use the Ubuntu font (together with Qt and fontconfig).

I’d like to use Ubuntu Light for regular text, and Ubuntu Regular for Bold text.

Short of editing both font files in fontforge and changing their OS/2 weight, how can I achieve this simply in fonts.conf?

Ubuntu-Light has a weight of 50, and Ubuntu-Regular has 80, so for normal text ("Sans"), Ubuntu Regular gets chosen.

If I add

```
<alias>
   <family>Sans</family>
   <prefer><family>Ubuntu Light</family></prefer>
</alias>
```

then Ubuntu-Light gets selected as default, but for bold I also get the Light variant:

```
> fc-match "Sans:style=bold"
Ubuntu-L.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Light"
```

Any ideas how I could tell it to use "Ubuntu Regular" for the bold style of Sans?